# Why would one gif load on a webpage and not another?

Tags: html, image, gif

This is completely making me crazy.  I have two GIF files in the same directory.  Navigating to them individually works, but when displaying them using an `<img>` tag, one loads and the other does not.

Here's a JSFiddle with a working GIF and the troublesome GIF:
http://jsfiddle.net/7Fxbt/

Comment: I can see both of them. Try something trivial - restart your browser. If it doesn't help, clear the image cache. Finally make sure your local hosts file is not routing the domain to your local environment, where perhaps the other image is missing.

Comment: They both loaded for me.

Comment: You can see both of them on the JSFiddle site?  What browser are you using?  I'm using latest Chrome.

Comment: yup, I can see them both too.  Windows 8.1 IE11 and latest Chrome 31.0.1650.57 and FF 25.0.1

Comment: I'm using Windows 8.1, FF 25

Comment: Wow - ok, IE9 works.  Why wouldn't chrome work?

Comment: I also see them both. Have you tried emptying your browser's cache in case it is retaining an older image of the site, or can you not see them in jsfiddle either?

Comment: Do you have adblock installed by any chance? :)

Comment: I see both in Chrome 31.0.1650.16 beta, OSX Mavericks

Comment: Nick, yes.  It's adblock.  Ugh.

Comment: Yeah I thought it might be, I think it sees the `ad` bit in the image name and auto blocks it.

Comment: Post an answer so I can accept you.

Comment: Why the downvoting?  Did I post this in the wrong place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Adblock` seems to be blocking the image if it contains `_ad`

Possible solution - rename the image and update `HTML` or `CSS` accordingly.